# Using JQuery can we modify the data in database ? In Asp.net?

Tags: jquery

In web application [asp.net], can we manifpulate or insert data using jquery.

Comment: Jquery is Javascript plugin. Javascript works client-side. You can only call via AJAX server-side methods to work with db.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery itself no, but you can make AJAX call with jQuery and manipulate data with ADO.NET on server side.

Answer (score 1):

> [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a cross-browser JavaScript library designed to simplify the
>   client-side scripting of HTML.

You need to use server side language like asp.net to contact with database on server but you can use jQuery to make your calls attractive using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

**Examples:**

- [Using jQuery to Insert a New Database Record](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/26/using-jquery-to-insert-a-new-database-record.aspx)
- [Many ways to communicate with your database using jQuery AJAX and ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/104/Many-ways-to-communicate-with-your-database-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASP.NET)
- [Calling database using jQuery AJAX and ASP.NET](http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/calling-database-using-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net/)

Comment: Ok naveed, is there any example are there using asp.net and jquery to modify the data in database

Comment: I added some nice articles about asp.net-database connection using jQuery/AJAX.